# Copy/Paste between workbooks (Subscript out of range)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having troubles figuring out the problem with my code. I am running through a folder, creating a sheet based on the filename, copying a single cell (A1) and passing it in the new sheet. However, I keep get the following error:

> Subscript out of range (Run-time error '9')

I have the following code:

```
Sub InsertDepartments()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
    file = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Departments\")
    While (file <> "")
        Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Start"))
        WS.Name = Left(file, InStr(file, ".") - 1)

        Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Departments\" & file).Sheets("XXX").Range("A1").Copy
        Sheets(WS.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        file = Dir
    Wend

End Sub
```

Can anyone see what is wrong in the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what line the error occurs on but try this: `file = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Departments\*.xlsx")` The `*` character will return all files with the name `.xlsx` in the folder, for example. Actually, I think the answer is that you need to open the workbook first, before you can copy any range values to it. So insert a `Workbooks.Open` method before the copy method. (Leaving first part in case it helps).

Comment: This error will pop up on any of your `Sheets()` or `Workbooks()` accesses if the item you're trying to use is not in the collection. Check the value of `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Departments\" & file` to make sure it's the name of an already-open workbook. Check that workbook has a sheet named "XXX" and check that your ActiveWorkbook has a sheet named `WS.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should resolve the problem. You were not opening the workbook prior to doing the copy/paste.

```
Sub InsertDepartments()
    Dim wbOutput As Workbook
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim file As Variant

    file = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Departments\*.xls*")
    Set wbOutput = ActiveWorkbook

    While (file <> "")

        Set wsOutput = wbOutput.Sheets.Add(After:=wbOutput.Sheets("Start"))
        wsOutput.Name = Left(file, InStr(file, ".") - 1)
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Departments\" & file)
        wbSource.Sheets("XXX").Cells.Copy
        wsOutput.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wbSource.Close False
        file = Dir
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a description of why this will help the OP.

Comment: Just a personal tweak - since OP just wants the values, you can skip the `.Copy` altogether, and just set the two ranges equal: `wsOutput.Range("A1").Value =  wbSource.Sheets("XXX").Cells.Value`.  (That should work. If not, you just have to size the two ranges equal to eachother).

Comment: I didn't set the ranges because depending on how much data is on the source sheet it could cause an "Out of memory" error.